# What is the meaning of "a lot of sleep last night."?

Tags: meaning

I have read this sentence but can not   understand "a lot of sleep last night."

```
 I didn't get a lot of sleep last night.
```

Can any one explain about it ?

Comment: Are there any particular parts about it that are questionable? 'Last' night? 'a lot'? 'get'? Otherwise this is a fairly basic grammar? What exactly is troubling about this sentence?

Answer (score 6):

The word "sleep" is also used as an Uncountable Noun, to express the number of hours of rest that you get.

"*I didn't get a lot of sleep*" equals:

> "*I didn't get enough sleep.*"

or

> "*I didn't get much sleep.*"

Answer (score 4):

It means the total number of hours you spent sleeping last night were few.

ie. you were awake most of the night.